# Is there a way to disable a non-dynamic class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, c++17, new-operator

Imagine a class which can be constructed only with the `new` operator. Is it possible to achieve this in the c++17 standard without deleting its destructor?

```
class Foo
{
    Foo(){}
    ~Foo(){}
    // delete non-dynamic constructor...?
}

// ...
Foo A; // compiling error
Foo* B = new Foo(); // ok
```

Comment: Afaik no, why should one?

Comment: There is no "dynamic" vs "non-dynamic" c'tor. C'tors initialize raw storage into objects. Doesn't matter how the storage came about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this by keeping all constructors private and wrapping the mandatory invocation of `new` in a factory function.

You should also disable copying the class.

```
class Foo
{
private:
  Foo() {}
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator= (const Foo&) = delete;

public:
  ~Foo() {}

  static std::unique_ptr<Foo> create() { return std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo{}); }
};
```

Comment: Make `create` static at least, elsewise it won't be useable.

Comment: @hellow Of course that was the intent, thanks. I seem to be not fully awake yet... :-(